# Windows batch script running 7zip expecting file rather than folder names

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a batch script that was working perfectly fine zipping a folder in the directory but for some reason after i made a name change , it seems to be looking for a "file" to zip and password protect, instead of a "folder" i cant find the syntax needed for it to zip the folder in the source directory

```
@ECHO ON
SET SourceDir=C:\job\Folder
SET DestDir=C:\job

CD /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%"') DO (
7z.exe a "%DestDir%\%%~NF" -p247BRIDGES "%SourceDir%\%%NXF"
)
EXIT
```

Comment: ok thank you for your comments.... the error is no file found, since it is looking for a file when in reality i want it to zip the folder not zip a file

Comment: What about adding a trailing backslash to the source to zip?

Comment: had tried the trailing backslash and does not work either

Comment: Please [edit] the exact error message (copied-and-pasted) into the question itself.

Comment: Your 7z command has a missing tilde `~` I'd also use `%%~fF` for the file `7z.exe a "%DestDir%\%%~NF" -psecret "%%~fF"` I'd also omit the password when posting ;-)

Comment: tried and still have same issue

Answer (score 0):

this helped me by adding .zip to destination and just zipping the file in the folder

```
 @ECHO ON

 SET SourceDir=C:\folder\source
 SET DestDir=C:\folder\destination

 CD /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
 FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%"') DO (
 7z.exe a "%DestDir%\%%~NF.zip" "%SourceDir%\%%~NXF"
 )
 EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what should be compressed into the archive files: directories or files.

The code is definitely written for compressing files into archive files.

The main mistake is the missing `~` in `%%NXF` which should be `%%~nxF` or even better just `%%F`.

But there are some more not so obvious mistakes which could result in wrong processing of some files.

It is very uncommon, but nevertheless possible that a file name starts with one or more leading spaces or a semicolon. The default `eol=;` results in ignoring file names output by **DIR** starting with a semicolon. So it would be better to use for example `eol=|` because of no file/folder name can contain a vertical bar. And it would be better to use `delims=` instead of using `TOKENS=*` removing all leading spaces/tabs from a line and assigning the rest of the line with spaces and tabs to specified loop variable `F` to avoid that files names with leading spaces are not correct processed by this batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=C:\job\Folder"
set "DestDir=C:\job"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceDir%" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -p247bridges -- "%DestDir%\%%~nI" "%SourceDir%\%%I"
endlocal
```

The command **FOR** starts with `cmd.exe /C` (more precisely `%ComSpec% /C`) a separate command process in background to execute the command line:

```
dir "C:\job\Folder" /A-D /B 2>nul
```

**DIR** outputs to handle **STDOUT** of started command process

- in bare format because of option `/B`
- just the names of files with extension because of option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- matching the implicit used wildcard pattern `*`
- which are found in directory `C:\job\Folder`
- with including also files with hidden attribute set.

The file names are output by **DIR** always without `"` even on containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` and without file path because of option `/S` (include subdirectories) is not used, too.

It could be that **DIR** does not find any file in directory `C:\job\Folder` matching the criteria in which case it outputs an error message to handle **STDERR**. This error message is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures the output to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes the captured text line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores always empty lines which do not occur here. **FOR** ignores by default also lines starting with `;` because of being the default end of line character which is the reason for usage of `eol=|` because of no file name can contain `|` at all. And **FOR** splits up by default a line into substrings (tokens) using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and assigns just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable. This line splitting behavior is not wanted here in case of a file name contains one or more spaces. For that reason `delims=` is used to specify an empty list of delimiters which disables line splitting behavior completely and for that reason results in getting entire line (= file name with extension without path) assigned to specified loop variable.

**FOR** runs for each file name assigned to loop variable `I` the application **7-Zip** to compress with default options the file specified with full qualified file name as last argument string into a password protected archive file in destination folder with name of the compressed file as archive file name and file extension appended by **7-Zip**.

Nearly the same task can be done a bit faster with:

```
@for %%I in ("C:\job\Folder\*") do @"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -p247bridges -y -- "C:\job\%%~nI" "%%I"
```

This single command line version designed for usage in a batch file processes just all non-hidden files in directory `C:\job\Folder` in comparison to above batch file which processes also files with hidden attribute set.

**FOR** searches in this case by itself for non-hidden files in directory `C:\job\Folder` and assigns the full qualified file name (file path + file name + file extension) to loop variable `I` and runs **7-Zip** to compress this file into an archive file into directory `C:\job` with archive file name being the same as the name of the compressed file.

The switch `-y` is added to prevent any prompt by **7-Zip**, for example on an archive file to create already existing in destination directory.

**FOR** assigns to loop variable `I` the full qualified file name of every found file in directory `C:\job\Folder` because of using full qualified path in wildcard pattern. **FOR** would assign to the loop variable just the file name with file extension on using just `*` instead of `C:\job\Folder\*` to find non-hidden files in current directory. And **FOR** would assign to the loop variable the file name of a found file with relative path if the wildcard pattern in round brackets is specified with a relative instead of an absolute path. Last but not list it would be also possible to specify more than one wildcard pattern each with no path or a relative path or an absolute path and **FOR** would process all wildcard patterns.

Open an x64 command prompt window on Windows x64 and run following two commands to better understand what **FOR** assigns to specified loop variable `I` depending on set of wildcard pattern(s):

```
cd /D %SystemRoot%
for %I in (*.exe System32\cm*.exe %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cm*.exe) do @echo %I
```

Output are with Windows directory being `C:\Windows` referenced with `%SytemRoot%` the file names of all non-hidden executables with file extension `.exe`

- without path found in Windows directory being the current directory matched by pattern `*` and
- of which file name starts with `cm` with relative path `System32\` found in system directory for x64 applications matched by pattern `System32\cm*.exe` and
- of which file name starts with `cm` with absolute path `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` found in system directory for x86 applications matched by pattern `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cm*.exe`.

But how to compress directories instead of files into archive files?

Well, in first batch file replace `/A-D` (attribute NOT directory) by `/AD` (attribute directory) to process all subdirectories in `C:\job\Folder` including hidden subdirectories and either append `\` to last argument of **7-Zip**, or use the switch `-r` for a recursive compression, or even both.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceDir=C:\job\Folder"
set "DestDir=C:\job"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceDir%" /AD /B 2^>nul') do "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -p247bridges -r -- "%DestDir%\%%~nI" "%SourceDir%\%%I\"
endlocal
```

And in single command line solution insert option `/D` between `for` and `%%I` to process all subdirectories in `C:\job\Folder` with exception of hidden subdirectories and modify also the **7-Zip** parameters list like above.

```
@for /D %%I in ("C:\job\Folder\*") do @"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -p247bridges -r -y -- "C:\job\%%~nI" "%%I\"
```

Open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

For help on usage of **7-Zip** from command line double click on its *.chm file in program files directory of **7-Zip** or start GUI version of **7-Zip** and open the help (same help file), select first tab **Contents**, double click on list item **Command Line Version** and read the referenced help pages.